# creating a field of 10x10 field

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code and looks correct, but somewhy new divs are not appears in the parent div. can someone explain to me why?

```js
var myGame = {
  fieldSize: 10,
  drawField: function() {
    setInterval(function () { 

      var parent = document.getElementById('parent')
      parent.innerHTML = '';
      for (var i=0; i<this.fieldSize; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        for (var j=0; j<this.fieldSize; j++) {
          var field = document.createElement('div');
          field.className = 'field';      
          row.appendChild(field);
        }
        parent.appendChild(row);      
      }
    }, 3000)
  }
}
myGame.drawField()
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setInterval creates another context, so `this.fieldSize` is `undefined`

```js
var myGame = {
  fieldSize: 10,
  drawField: function() {
    setInterval(() => { 

      var parent = document.getElementById('parent')
      parent.innerHTML = '';
      for (var i=0; i<this.fieldSize; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        for (var j=0; j<this.fieldSize; j++) {
          var field = document.createElement('div');
          field.className = 'field';   
          row.appendChild(field);
        }
        parent.appendChild(row);   
      }
    }, 3000)
  }
}
myGame.drawField()
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```